# What is the subject to study continuous function?

Tags: general-topology

What is the subject specialized to study continuous function?

I am not sure if it is the topology and what topics of topology study continuous function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The study of continuous functions can fall under the subject of Analysis or Topology. From the topological perspective, a continuous function is a function for which the inverse image of a open set is open. This definition applies to any topology, including that of metric spaces. Topology tends to be a more abstract approach to continuity. Topology is concerned with types of functions that preserve topologies, such as homeomorphisms.

Analysis often approaches continuity from the perspective of metric spaces, though often weak topologies are often used. Analysis is where you will deal with limits of continuous functions on metric spaces, such as the convergence of Taylor series or approximating continuous functions with polynomials. This is also where integration theory lives.